# Material ui date time picker theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material ui date pickers is using the default theme instead of using my custom theme. How to correct this and make the picker to use my custom theme instead of default one.

Code Sandbox [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-2y6gq)

Comment: It is difficult for anyone to help correct your code when you don't include any of it in your question. Please include a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem and put that same code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put whatever you have tried in the question.
Anyway, You can define your own theme in the index.js file.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#008080"
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#4caf50',
        },

    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <App />
        </MuiThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It will now pick the theme you have here.

Here is the exact code that is working like I said.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider
  libInstance={moment}
  utils={MomentUtils}>
  <KeyboardDateTimePicker
     autoOk
     fullWidth
     size="small"
     animateYearScrolling
     inputVariant="outlined"
     value={start_time}
     keyboardIcon={<DateRangeIcon color="secondary" />}
     placeholder={showStartTime ? "" : "Test not scheduled"}
     onChange={handleDateChange} />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: Actually I have done the same. The problem occured when I used a material ui pickers. I am not sure but I think may be using Muipickersutilsprovider is overriding my custom theme with default theme. Because as soon as I inserted a date picker all my theme color gets reset to default theme colors.

Comment: I have used MuiPickers in two of my projects and it didn't behave like that, it is picking colors from whatever I provide in the primary: { main: "here"}. I have added my code.

Can you this particular code in code sandbox and share.

Comment: Thanks Sahil for taking time for my issue. I tried updating the dependencies and it worked now it is using custom theme. But now another problem arises which is the picker dialog is appearing without any styles. PFA the link to the sandbox of this code: (https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-2y6gq)

Comment: @Sumit you got me there I was trying to debug and finally found that your theme is altering the calendar component styles. You have changed MuiInput, MuiButton styles in the theme which is altering the input and buttons in the calendar component

Comment: Oh so what should I do now because I have used the custom theme in many other components.

Comment: No matter what library you may use your theme will alter them too. I guess you must look into your theme and make the adjustments accordingly so that it doesn't hamper the CSS of the library you are using. You must change the theme that's what I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem in the context of MUI v5.14... and x-date-pickers-pro v.6.18... It seems MUI doesn't directly expose DatePicker as a themable component in the same way as MuiTextField or MuiButton. So, I see only three options in this case:

1. Change sx of DatePicker locally =)
2. We can override global specific styles for our needs. For example, if I want to change the label color, it would look like this:

   ```
    export function yourDesignTokens(mode: PaletteMode): ThemeOptions {
          return {
            // ...
            components: {
              // ...
              MuiInputLabel: {
                styleOverrides: {
                  root: {
                    color: (theme) => theme.palette.primary.main,
                    // Other styles
                  },
                },
              },
              MuiOutlinedInput: {
                styleOverrides: {
                  notchedOutline: {
                    borderColor: (theme) => theme.palette.primary.main,
                    // Other styles
                  },
                },
              },

              // ... other component overrides
            },
          }
   ```

   }

However, this approach seems unfriendly for other components that use the same implementation.

3. We can control styles via slotProps, for example:

//your tokensSheet:

```
MuiDatePicker: {
        defaultProps: {
          slotProps: {
            textField: {
              color: 'warning',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
```

But these are primarily aimed at more complex customizations, like replacing entire components or modifying the layout structure of the picker. For instance, you can modify the action bar, layout, tabs, and toolbar through these properties.

So, for now, I've decided to stick with local styling =)